# Get size of queue of message in FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Is it possible to get the size of FCM message queue at a time when the FCM notification received on the device?.

I have a situation where I calling my web service and also save to my local database(`realm` in my case) at a time when I got the FCM from my APIs, this is working perfectly when my application received FCM notification one-by-one, but when a device is disconnected for like 10-12hrs and once after that when device get connected to network a bulk of notification received at a time which causes large number of web service call and thread for saving data in local database at a time which causes some performance issues to my application.

I'm trying to reduce this calls to as minimum as possible according to the notification types.

Are there any good methods to do this efficiently?

Comment: instead immediately call your web services everytime your phone has FCM, what about save your message first to the local database, like sqlite, and calling your web services with Scheduled Task, like Alarm Manager, with 10 seconds interval, more or less. The downside is your web services call cannot go real time. But on positive side, you can query your message fist before call your web service.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira But saving messages to my local database (`realm` in my case) causes lots of connections to the database which causes threadPoolException, which I also want to handle to save data in single call